# datatable static html loaded all rows before pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have lots rows, but when i am refresh the page, 1st all rows initialized then pagination as default 10 rows. I would like to show 10 rows while reload and refresh page. How to fix it?

https://jsfiddle.net/abilashu/b8fs7Lud/

```
Please check fiddle above
```

Comment: I am unable to recreate your issue using your code and some sample data.  Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: OK - thank you for the update. I saw the problem happen once out of approx. 20 full refreshes. I cannot see any obvious cause - but you can try replacing your resources with the latest minified versions from [the official download location](https://datatables.net/download/index). This general issue is mentioned [here](https://mail.datatables.net/forums/discussion/18350/weird-view-when-loading-before-pagination), where browser version was suggested as one possible reason. Maybe someone else can provide a better suggestion.

Comment: I did look at the Fiddle. The resources you get from the download site are different - for jQuery.

Comment: (Minor point: It is recommended to show the code in the question itself, so that the question does not rely on solely external links. The Fiddle is very helpful as an additional resource - but the question should try to be self-contained as far as possible.)

Comment: because huge code is not working with sinipet in stackoverflow

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your comment. The code in the Fiddle is not "huge", and would work in a snippet with no problems (as long as you also avoid providing a question which _only_ contains code - and which does not contain any commentary).  Anyway, it is, of course, up to you - but questions like this may attract down-votes and close-votes, so I was just trying to help you.